# Xamarin IOS UIActivityViewController ExcludedActivityTypes how to include linked

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to exclude Linkedin but when i checked [UIActivityType](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIActivityType/) Class, I found only below members.

AddToReadingList
AirDrop 
AssignToContact
CopyToPasteboard
Mail
Message
OpenInIBooks
PostToFacebook
PostToFlickr
PostToTencentWeibo
PostToTwitter
PostToVimeo 
Print
SaveToCameraRoll

Is there a way we can exclude linkedin?

Comment: Your question is asking to include and exclude LinkedIn, which one are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

I thought this radar concerning third-party values was closed, but it is still open :-(

- http://openradar.appspot.com/20170408

...

The `ExcludedActivityTypes` is just an array of `NSString`s that include the bundle id of the share extension. So use `com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension` to exclude linkedin.

#### Example:

```
var activityItemsNSUrl = NSUrl.FromString("http://stackoverflow.com");
var activityItemsString = new NSString("StackOverflow");

var activityItems = new NSObject[] { activityItemsString, activityItemsNSUrl };
var activityViewController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null)
{
    ExcludedActivityTypes = new NSString[] {
        UIActivityType.PostToVimeo,
        new NSString("com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension"),
        UIActivityType.PostToFlickr
    }
};
PresentViewController(activityViewController, true, () => { });
```

Re: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk

Comment: still bug, it is not identifying linkedin

Comment: @user2021837 Not fixed in iOS 11 either and I'm assuming it will not be since system-level integration to the social media accounts have been removed in 11

Comment: @user2021837 `identifying`? Just to clarify, you are trying to **exclude** linked correct?

Comment: All other system provided UIActivityType are working but when i  add linkedin `new NSString("com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension")` it shows in share. @SushiHangover

Comment: @user2021837 Unless Apple addresses that radar/issue with a future fix there is nothing you can do to exclude it from the `UIActivityViewController`.  I had a client that tried to avoid the system-provided share UI and ended up swizzling ObjC methods but that led to an App store rejection.

Comment: @ SushiHangover thank you let see when they will fix it.